# Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x74acff0> on <ViewController: 0x82b25a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am new to objective c programming and i'm making an app. I am using osx 10.8.4 and xcode 4.6. I am trying to (modal)segue from one view controller to another in a single-view application. I have already given the segue identifier for the segue and put a segue in the storyboard. However, when i try to segue the console shows this:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x74acff0> on <ViewController: 0x82b25a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Here is my code for my first view controller .m file(contains code to segue):

```
 Viewcontroller.m:

 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import "hackScreen.h"
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
 #import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

- (IBAction)hackStarter:(id)sender {

NSString *checker = [_redBoulderRepublic text];
int soLong = [checker length];

UIAlertView *wrongNumber = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Invalid number"
                            message:@"Please enter a valid phone number"
                            delegate:nil
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

if (soLong == 10){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueOne" sender:sender];

}
else{
   [wrongNumber show]; 
}

 }
 - (void)dealloc {
[_redBoulderRepublic release];
[super dealloc];
}
 - (IBAction)keyboardKiller:(id)sender {
[_redBoulderRepublic resignFirstResponder];
 }



@end
```

And my .h file:

```
 Viewcontroller.h:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "hackScreen.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)hackStarter:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *redBoulderRepublic;
- (IBAction)keyboardKiller:(id)sender;


@end
```

Comment: Can you add a picture of your storyboard?

Comment: Do you have something other than ViewController's view on the screen when you do the segue?

Comment: I can't add a picture cause I don't have enough rep

Answer (score 4):

The error means that your `ViewController` isn't currently displayed but you are trying to perform a segue to another controller. In order to perform a transition from one view controller to another, the first view controller needs to be visible (or at least added to the view hierarchy).

In other words, you are calling `hackStart` before the instance of `ViewController` has been displayed.

Comment: In the simulator I can correctly see viewcontroller but the error displays when I try to segue.